# What kind of CSS is this?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I was looking at an old installation of mediawiki which is not rendering css properly the code in the Chrome Dev Tools is showing CSS like this

`{{{border-width|1}}}px solid {{{titleborder|{{{border|#ababab}}}}}}`

Not able to understand what is the pre-processor used and why its not working. Can someone hint to some direction.

Here in the image the span text is not rendered as a blue bar since The CSS breaks because of the template code. Not sure where to look for this CSS Template issue. Isnt much aware about the Media Wiki Architecture.

[image]

Comment: It's not a pre processor, it's a template engine

Comment: thanks can you also hint me to why it might not be working i mean its just printing like that in browser.

Comment: The chrome dev tools show you the line in the css this originates from. Post the original code referenced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this CSS is used inline in a template on your page.

`{{{border-width|1}}}` means “use the value of the parameter border-width, or 1 if none is given”. In this case, the parameters to the template are not expanded. There are a number of possible reasons, though until you show us the template code, or give us a link to the page, we can only guess:

1. Syntax errors in the template (like a missing bracket somewhere, or a stray `<nowiki>` tag)
2. A complex template chain passed the [expansion depth limit](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Expansion#Expansion_of_names_and_values).
3. Too many templates on one page (surpassing the post-expand include size)

You can check the category `Category:Pages containing omitted template arguments` to see if it is any of the latter, though I strongly suspect the first.

Edit: Also, before doing anything else, you can try to simply purge the page, to re-render it.

Edit2: Now that we have a screenshot, it looks like some wikicode that an extension could have thrown in there. Start by disabling all extensions, and, if that helps, enable them again one by one.

Comment: we just did migration of a working mediawiki installation from a windows 2003 to windows2012. When you say show us the template code which file you refer to I am not a mediawiki guy so not sure which file i should look for.

Comment: Somewhere in the wikicode of that page, there is a template call, e.g. `{{MyTemplate|param=123|param2=abc}}`. The wikicode for that template will be on the page `Template:MyTemplate`

Comment: I have attached a image to show what i am facing. I still cannot figure out what file (code) i can produce since its a css (not on the page) which is genric and usually create a blue bar for a portlet box. Can you direct me to what code i can possibly look for this CSS. Or may be go and harcode this to use a particular color instead of template.

Comment: If you are sure this isn't a page template, I would guess that you have an ill behaved extension installed (judging from you screenshot, you seem to have quite a few extensions running). Did you try to disable all extensions, to see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the help, We finally found that one of the Template on page was not working. Not sure why it was not but lowering the php version solved the issue.